# Find Records Based on Distant belongsToMany > belongsTo Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm attempting to display a product page with a list of assets that match a specific asset type.  For example, for product "Acme Cream", there are two assets: nutrition-facts.pdf (of type Document) and marketing-video.mp4 (of type Video).  On the product page, I'd like to display the first asset that match the 'Video' asset type (if any exist).

I have the following relationships:

The Product model includes a DB column `asset_id`.

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * The assets that belong to the product.
     */
    public function assets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Asset', 'product_asset');
    }
}
```

The Asset model includes DB columns `id` and `asset_type_id`.

```php
class Asset extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the asset type that owns the asset.
     */
    public function asset_type()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\AssetType');
    }

    /**
     * The products that belong to the asset.
     */
    public function products()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'product_asset');
    }
}
```

The AssetType model has two DB columns `id` and `name`.

```php
class AssetType extends Model
{
    /**
     * A asset type can have many assets
     */
    public function assets()
    {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Asset');
    }
}
```

How can I efficiently fetch the one product asset by filtering on asset_type?  Keep in mind, I've already queried the DB using Product::find(id) and passed that data into the view.  Will this require another query (eager loading might help with that).  I know I could use a `foreach` loop, but it seems to me there's gotta be a nicer, more 'eloquent' way.

I'm trying to use it in this situation (pseudo code) on the product detail page (*show.blade.php*):

if assets matching type 'Video', then display first in this div.  Else, don't display the div.

It seems like it should be a simple line:

```php
$product->assets()->asset_type()->where('name', '=', 'Video')->first()
```

The closest I've come so far to this is this ugly looking thing:

```php
>>> $product = App\Product::with(['assets'])->find(1)
>>> $product->assets()->with(['asset_type' => function ($query) { $query->where('name', '=', 'Video'); }])->get()
```

However, it still returns all assets, except the "asset_type" attribute is null for those that don't match.  Adding `->whereNotNull('asset_type')->get()` only results in an error that `asset_type` column cannot be found.

Also, this sounds like a chance to use the "[Has Many Through](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)" relationship, but I'm unclear how to set this up.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: if no video type asset then don't display product ?

Comment: Is the belongs to many works? As far as i remember The intermediate table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and contains the  table1_id and table2_id columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to eager-load your relationship with filtering:

**Assuming you fetch the relationship with your product info**

```
$typeName = 'Video';

$product = App\Product::with([
            'asset' => function($query) use($typeName) {
                //Filter asset by type
                //See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads
                return $query->whereHas('asset_type',function($query) use($typeName) {
                    //Filter where the type's name equals..
                    //Each query is relative to its scope, in this case the 'type' relationship which refers to your 'type' Model
                    return $query->where('name','=',$typeName);
                });
            },
            //Nested relationship loading: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations
            'assets.asset_type'
            ])
            ->find(1);


$assets = $product->assets;
```

**Assuming you fetch only the assets**

```
$productId = 1;
$typeName = 'Video';

//Returns a collection of eloquent models
$assets = Asset::whereHas('product',function($query) use ($productId) {
                //Filter product by its id
                return $query->where('id','=',$productId);
            })
            ->whereHas('asset_type',function($query) use ($typeName) {
                //Filter type by its name
                return $query->where('name','=',$typeName);
            })
            ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this!  I was really racking my brain.